# System performance drops when even 1 core is busy on Ubuntu 18.04 or 18.10

Tags: performance

I'm performing numerical simulation on Ubuntu 18.10 (also tried 18.04) using OpenFOAM opensource package. The problem is when I'm running a simulation even on one core, the system performance drops significantly slowing every process including if I run another simulation or even using Ubuntu for every day usage...

For example if I run one simulation it will take 600s, when I try to run another simulation with completely the same configuration, the simulation time goes beyond 850s and so on...even Ubuntu itself when running simulation becomes laggy...

The running simulation is not even IO intensive, so I don't think my HDD is the problem.

Here is my system spec:

OS: Ubuntu 18.10, kernel 4.18.16

MB: ASUS Prime x299-deluxe

CPU: Intel Core i7 skylake-x 7820x 8 core 16 threads

RAM: G.Skill Ripjaw V 4x8 GB 2400MHz

PSU: Cooler Master v750

HDD: Toshiba 1TB 7200RPM

Regards,

D. Khazaei

Answer (score 0):

Try forcing your application to use the last system core your processor has available.  Make sure it is an actual core VS a hyperthread.

For example, do a ps and learn the process Id of this simulation.  Then do:

taskset -p 0x14

I believe that should put it on the last core (no hyperthread) for a single core.  You can do multiple cores as well, just need to tweak the taskset parameters.

Also, try running "top" and pay attention to processor usage to confirm that the program you're running is actually using 1 core.